# How do you to find the limit of $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have some trouble with finding the limit of sequences. In our analysis lecture we didn't discuss proper way to find a limit, just some examples but more case by case situation. So I have trouble finding limits in general without just putting in a high number. The only thing I know is L'Hospital, which we didn't even had in the lecture and I probably can't use here because of the sum? Right now I'm stuck with:

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2}$

Normally I'd just say if $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}$ than I'd have $\frac{\infty}{\infty^2}$ (because the numerator would be the sum of $1$ up to $n$ and in this case it would be infinity), which is just $\frac{1}{\infty}$ which is $0$. Is that a correct way to even think about it or am I doing it wrong?

Please help me elevate my thinking. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

By Riemann sums:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}=\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx = \frac{1}{2}.$$
On the other hand, that also follows from $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k = \frac{1}{n^2} \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n^2}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I go it. Don't know how I couldn't see that. Thanks!! (and thanks to everyone else :))

Comment: you are welcome. it is natural in mathematics, it happens for me many times :)

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {k}{n^2}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {k}{n} \frac 1n= \int_{0}^{1} x dx=\frac 12$ .